# No installer icon in Desktop when customized Ubuntu 10.10 using Remastersys

Tags: 10.10

I just customised Ubuntu 10.10 using Remastersys using 'dist' option. But, when I booted the custom iso image to pendrive & booted using it, the live desktop is showing up. But, how can I install it? There is no installer in the desktop. Can anyone help?

Comment: To anyone else considering voting to close: This has helpful upvoted answers (and consequently doesn't appear in the list of unanswered questions). Since it's answered, it's neither abandoned nor off-topic (since only new/unanswered questions about EoL releases are off-topic; we don't close the old ones).

Answer (score 1):

The install command should still be the forth item down in the Admin menu.  Remaster doesn't pick up anything from the desktop but the command should still be in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the short cut in `/etc/skel` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need install the `ubiquity` and `ubiquity-frontend-gtk` before create your iso file.

Answer (score 0):

Ubiquity installs automatically with the Remastersys package, check to make sure it's present.  Also check to be sure you Internet connection is working; it won't create an install icon if it can't connect to the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The steps go like this:<sup>1</sup>
1. Insert the disk in your CD/DVD tray.
2. Boot your custom remastersys Ubuntu live CD.
3. If you don’t see an install icon on the desktop, then open the terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>).
4. Now in the terminal just type `ubiquity --desktop %k gtk_ui` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Now you have the Ubuntu Install window in front of you. Enjoy.

<sup>1</sup><sub>http://www.techkamar.blogspot.in/2013/09/remstersys-cutom-live-cd-install-icon.html</sub>